# Automatically truncate 8 digits with two decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, decimalformat

I have textbox of Maxlength(11) allowing 8 digits, 1 decimal point and 2 precision. I have the following cases:

1. If the user keys in 11 digits, it must consider the first 8 digits, add a decimal point, then use the next two for precision.
2. If the user enters a whole digit alone, it must autoappend `.00`.
3. When leaving the textbox, it adds commas within the digits. Eg, `12,345,678.90`

I am using the below function to add commas

```
function addCommas(nStr) {
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}

// Using toFixed(2) to make .00
```

I am not able to automatically,adjust the available values. Do you have any suggestions to make all this in one function? Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: _Case 1:_ What happens to the last digit? _Case 2:_ What happens if you enter 11 digits? 10 digits? 9 digits? _Case 3:_ `12,345,678.90` will exceed a length of 11. In fact, it seems all cases may exceed the max length. After clarifying all three cases what exactly is the problem you are having? Show some example input/output. Finally, don't try to do this all in one function -- divide and conquer e.g. one function truncates/rounds another function comma-formats...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, why don't you use javascript **substring** function, and simple if else condition..
Created the [Plnkr Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/2FXX6hP6wh0epbWlb1rH?p=preview) for your reference, if this is what you want..